# The product of (first) chern classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, intersection-theory

I was reading Fulton's *Intersection Theory* and came across this useful formula for the chern class of the tensor product:
$$
c_r(E\otimes L) = \sum_{i=0}^r c_1(L)^ic_{r-i}(E).
$$
However, I couldn't find a definition of what exactly the product of two chern classes was. Is it purely formal or can it be simplifed?

In particular, for a line bundle $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}(D)$ on a variety $X$, we know $c_1(\mathcal{L}) = D$. It's tempting to write 
$$
c_1(\mathcal{L})^2 = D^2 = D.D
$$
where $D.D$ is the self-intersection as usual, but I can't really justify this from the axioms or basic results I've found.

Is the above true? If so, how does one justify it, and if not, how should I think about products and power of (first) chern classes?

Thanks.

Comment: It is just the cup product...

Comment: By the way, as Fulton defines it in terms of Segre classes, he states in the definition of Chern class: "Here the $s_j(E)$ are regarded as endomorphisms of $A^{\ast}X$, with products denoting composition; "

Comment: @AlanMuniz Thanks for the reply. I'm still a little confused though: if we think of the cup product as the Poincar\'{e} dual to the intersection form, and $\text{Pic}(X) \simeq H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^\ast_X)$, then it still feels like $c_1(\mathcal{O}(D))c_1(\mathcal{O}(D'))$ should be $D.D'$ since $c_1(\cdot) \in A^\ast(X)$ and $[A][B] = [A\cap B]$ for $[A], [B] \in A^\ast(X)$. Is there a way to formalize this, or is it just wishful thinking? If the latter, where does my reasoning break down?

Comment: $c_i(E)$ is in $H^{2i}(X,\mathbb{Z})$  you can use the cup profuct in any compatible cohomology...

Comment: And, yes! For a line bundle $L$ associated to a divisor $D$, $c_1(L)^r = D^r$.

Comment: @AlanMuniz Gotcha - thanks! P.S. if you compile your comments as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Ok. Later I'll post the answer. This mobile app is not very good :( The self intersection is defined somewhere in Fulton's book. I don't remember where now.